# How to disconnect internet when VPN fails?

Tags: networking, vpn

Normally I'm connected to the Internet with a VPN, but sometimes it fails and some programs may automatically start to use the default unsecure connection.

How do I disconnect all the internet until the VPN connection is back up? I want to make sure all the traffic goes exclusively over VPN.

Comment: PIA VPN has this function "Built in" It's called a VPN Killswitch.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the IP address of your VPN, after you connect to a network, you can create a route to that VPN server IP via the default gateways IP and remove the default route to prevent connections anywhere else.

```bsh
export vpn_ip=VPN_SERVER_IP
export gateway_ip=$(ip route | grep default | cut -d" " -f 3)

sudo ip route del default via $gateway_ip
sudo ip route add $vpn_ip via $gateway_ip
```

This would prevent any connections, regardless of VPN connectivity, to the VPN IP, but still allow the VPN connection to establish/re-establish.

---

The problem with other solutions suggested is that you need a connection to connect to a VPN, so, you must connect to LAN/WiFi, you can't just delete/disable those connections.

Answer (score 0):

Tried unplugging the cable until VPN comes back up?

In any case you could delete all the Wired/Wireless connections that Network Manager has stored and just leave the VPN ones there with the "automatic" option activated so when VPN comes back up it will connect to it automatically.

[image]

Just to make my point a little more clear. In the Wired, Wireless, Mobile Broadband and DSL set any connections you might have there to not automatic (Remove the **Connect Automatically** check from the checkbox). Or to be more drastic remove the connection completely. The only one that should be in **Connect Automatically** is the VPN connection you have.

With this you should have a system that automatically connects to the VPN when it is available. When it disconnects the system will stay offline until the VPN comes back.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to make it automatically (even if I'm not around the computer)

Comment: Then this one will work. Removing all other connections from the Wired/Wireless tabs in the network manager and leaving only the VPN one with the automatic setting will leave the PC in a state where it does not matter what other connections appear. It will connect to the VPN automatically when it appears again.

Comment: So next I will have to manually add them back, connect back to VPN and remove the connections?

Comment: Or just simply leave them without the "Connect automatically". That way you do not need to delete them. Of course they will be in manual mode so you would need to click on them to connect them. The only one that should stay in "Connect automatically" would be the one about the VPN. If this helps remember to accept/upvote the answer. Only if it helps.

Comment: It starts using the main connection after the VPN disconnects - same as before